# Function for densest sphere packing inside a sphere

Tags: function, computational-geometry

I'm trying to write a function for the densest packing of identical spheres inside a spherical boundary.

I'm thinking it will be something like spherepack(c,r,n), where:

c - centre of the boundary sphere (x,y,z coordinates)

r - radius of the boundary sphere

n - number of identical spheres to be packed inside the boundary

I want the outputs to be the x,y,z coordinates of the centre of each packed sphere. Does anyone know how this could be done?

Comment: The cubic packing is knownto be the densest in unbounded space. But solving the problem for a spherical space looks terrible.

Comment: What if it wasn't for the general case, but for a specific low number of spheres, say 4?

Comment: Four sphere pack as a tetrahedron, there's no point. The fun starts at five.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_packing_in_a_sphere

Answer (score 1):

How about what you might call the 'brute force' method. ie Model what would happen if you had a pile of n unit sized spheres and just tried packing them together in every possible close-packed configuration, and then measured the smallest containing sphere for the pack. I can imagine an algorythm for that, but it is not very programatically efficient, or mathmatically beautiful. Would it have to run fast, or just get the right answer?

Unfortunately, the assumption that close packing is densest is not correct :(

Comment: look at the link above. Many of the results are not close packed configurations.

Comment: @agentp That's interesting. I hadn't thought of that. From 6 to 7 spheres is interesting, and quite easy to visualise. I take back what I said, and will have to think again. It seemed so 'obvious' that close packing must be optimal.